# How to declare Maven/Java library, e.g. JFreeChart, as dependency?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, jfreechart

I'm trying to add JFreeChart library as a dependency of a sbt project.

I added the following to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.jfree" %% "jfreechart" % "1.0.14"
```

However, it doesn't work.

The pom file at http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.14/jfreechart-1.0.14.pom says:

```
<artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
<groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
<version>1.0.14</version>
```

How can I use a maven library like this in sbt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've used `%%` before the artifactId, which causes SBT to append the version of scala. So you're actually trying to find the artifact that has an id of `jfreechart_2.10` (or whatever your version of Scala is).

This is useful for [cross built](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html) libraries. Java libraries are not cross built, so use:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.jfree" % "jfreechart" % "1.0.14"
```